# Two mystical trees

Tags: wordplay, letters, graph-theory

**Behold, the mystical Tree of B:**

[image: Tree_of_B]

**Notice that every path from trunk to canopy forms a word.  You should see 16 words (from left to right:  BLOOM, BLOOD, BLOWN, BLOWS, BLAND, BLANK, BLASÉ, BLAST, BROOK, BROOM, BROWN, BROWS, BRAID, BRAIN, BRASH, BRASS).**

**Once upon a time, the Tree of B had a sister tree, the Tree of C.  Tragically, the Tree of C was chopped down by a horde of hideous hobgoblins.  Here are her remains:**

[image: remains_of_Tree_of_C]

**Legend has it that whoever reassembles the Tree of C will be blessed with untold riches.**

Text version:

```
The stump shows the letter C

The piled wood shows the following letters:
A, A, A, D, E, E, E, E, E, E, H, H, K, K, K, K, M, M, M, N, R, R, R, S, S, S, S, S, T, T
```

Comment: I'm confused, not sure how half of the tags here apply or what else we might be supposed to do?

Comment: @LukasRotter — It looks like you knew what to do!  I was unsure how to tag this puzzle.  It is certainly a wordplay jigsaw puzzle.  It is also a binary tree, but there are no tags for "binary tree".  However, a tree is a type of graph, and a graph is geometrical in some people's minds.  And, the puzzle involves a certain amount of topology because you need to connect things together in the right way!

Comment: A tree of D: `drona drony drool droop dried drier drink drinn donum donut donee doney dorab doria dorts dorty`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Reassembled tree:

> ```
> C
> ├── H
> │   ├── E
> │   │   ├── S
> │   │   │   ├── T
> │   │   │   └── S
> │   │   └── E
> │   │       ├── R
> │   │       └── K
> │   └── A
> │       ├── R
> │       │   ├── M
> │       │   └── T
> │       └── S
> │           ├── E
> │           └── M
> └── R
>     ├── E
>     │   ├── E
>     │   │   ├── K
>     │   │   └── D
>     │   └── A
>     │       ├── K
>     │       └── M
>     └── A
>         ├── N
>         │   ├── K
>         │   └── E
>         └── S
>             ├── H
>             └── S
> ```

Words:

> CHEST, CHESS, CHEER, CHEEK, CHARM, CHART, CHASE, CHASM, CREEK, CREED, CREAK, CREAM, CRANK, CRANE, CRASH, CRASS

Comment: I was surprised to find out that CRASE and CRANS are also (technically) valid.

Comment: @H.v.M. After CRA: N is followed by K or E (not S) and S is followed by H or S (not E).

Comment: @PaulEvans If you switch the last terminal E and S then H.v.M.'s tree works just as well. (The word "crase" being obsolete, notwithstanding).